# Breeze ContextProvider For EF6 build error

Tags: breeze, breeze-sharp

After I installed the ContextProvider for EF6 via nuget, I get the following build error.

> Assembly 'Breeze.ContextProvider, Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=f6085f1a45e2ac59' uses 'Newtonsoft.Json,
>   Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
>   which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json,
>   Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'

Any help is appreciated to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breeze needs a newer version of Newtonsoft than what you have installed.  Go to Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Updates, and look for an update to Json.Net, or type:

```
Update-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

In the Package Manager Console